# Regular expression for replacing special characters with underscore

Tags: android, regex

If I want a name to contain only letters, numbers, dashes and underscores, any other characters need to replaced with underscore. How can I do it with regular expression?

Comment: `String#replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]", "_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
String dirtyString = "This*is#a*-very_dirty&String";
System.out.print(dirtyString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]","_"));  // Replace all with "_"
                                                                 // except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, 
                                                                // '-', '_' and space.

// System prints  This_is_a_-very_dirty_String
```